# Convert Visual C++ console project to Forms Project (Visual Studio 2010)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

In Visual Studio 2010, I have a CLR C++ console project that I would like to change into a Forms project, so that I can add a form and use the designer and whatnot. Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you just create a new project?  It isn't like you can really salvage anything by making such a switch.  Nor should you.  Just copy non-UI related source code files or put them in a separate project that you share.

Comment: @Hans Passant: I had that idea before, though I can't seem to manage to link everything properly in that new project, even when I pretty much copy over all include paths and library paths. So after some tedious trial and error, I decided to try and take the lame way out by simply converting the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare the old project templates then make necessary changes like adding references to winforms and changing the entry point function from winmain back to main.

See http://jiangsheng.net/2012/12/17/how-to-migrating-a-clr-console-visual-c-project-to-windows-forms/ for details. This article is written for 2012 but should work in 2010.

Comment: Thank you. I will give this a try on Tuesday -- I have four days off now.